# Windows dxdiag, msinfo32 alternatives for ubuntu

Tags: command-line, windows, system, alternative, tools

Are there any commands or tools for that?

Answer (score 2):

**dxdiag** is actually a troubleshooting tool for **DirectX**. **dmidecode** is a tool for dumping a computer's DMI table contents in a human-readable format. This table contains a description of the system's hardware components, as well as other useful pieces of information such as serial numbers and BIOS revision. Thanks to this table, you can retrieve this information without having to probe for the actual hardware. While this is a good point in terms of report speed and safeness, this also makes the presented information possibly unreliable.

The DMI table doesn't only describe what the system is currently made of, it also can report the possible evolution (such as the fastest supported CPU or the maximal amount of memory supported). Look at [this link](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) for more information.

If this approximate equivalent couldn't give desired information, one can use some of diagnostics tools in Linux such as:

- lshw
- lspci
- lsusb
- ps
- top
- lm-sensors
- df